# Mutex the right way

Tags: kotlin, locking, mutex, kotlinx.coroutines

What is the right way to "synchronize" function which mutates shared state using Mutex? Using Mutex within a coroutine started with `launch()` or `async()` works as expected, but if I start a coroutine with `runBlocking()` the thread looks like blocked (locked) for a very long time. The thing is that the function might be called from multiple threads and I cannot solve this with thread confinement. What's the right way to use Mutex in this scenario?

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to design your software in so that avoids usage of `Mutex` and other forms of shared mutable state altogether. If you have some resource or data structure that needs to be shared you can always encapsulate this data structure inside a separate coroutine and communicate with this coroutine when you need to do anything with this data structure. This design pattern is known as an *actor*. An actor is a pair  of a coroutine and a channel it reads incoming messages from.

The advantage of this approach is that you can communicate asynchronously with an actor. If you send a message to an actor and don't wait for a response, then you can continue the work without having to wait for an actor to finish processing your message.

You can read a bit more about actors in [the guide to kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md).

Comment: But.. is this expected behavior of Mutex?